# Windows theme messed up fonts - how to fix

Tags: windows-7, fonts, themes

Just installed [Abstract dark theme](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows/abstract-dark-download-theme) on Windows 7. Now many applications have messed up fonts (greasy, not sharp) and changing back to old one does not help. I don't know where too look, restarting pc, using defaults settings in Fonts, changing default fonts nothing helped. What can this be? Maybe worth mentioning that i use 135% DPI, but playing with this didn't help much either, things seem normal only when i use 100% DPI.

[image: Old vs new app]

Comment: Why would you increase the DPI? The computer is probably rendering them just as you asked. Your *monitor*, however, cannot comply.

Comment: Try a System Restore back to before you installed the theme.

Comment: I have DPI on 135% for two years now, so this was not changed now. Image up and below both have same DPI, but now fonts are blurred.

Comment: Tried, but System Restore is turned off ;( But i have system image few days old, so I can try this if no other solution.

Comment: Interesting thing to reduce number of possible problems, i design application in Visual Studio, in designer i can change fonts and all are clear in designer no matter which i choose. But when I run that app, all fonts are blurry.

Answer (score 0):

Just theory for now but in %windir%\Fonts MS Sans Seif Regular looks pixelized. Other fonts look normal for now, is it possbile that blurry fonts are consequence of anti-aliasing or some other transformation over pixelized font? [image: Pixelized sserifee.fon]

Comment: Although this seams like problem, it seams that this is not main problem. I have tried with Visual studio trick and building some app with Font that is nice in %windir%\Fonts, and when app runs it is also blurred, although it is nice in Visual Studio designer. WTF?